# Rails fails to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install rails on a Mac but am getting some strange errors:

> sudo gem install rails
>   Successfully installed rails-3.2.3
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.3...
>   file 'lib' not found
>   Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.3...
>   file 'lib' not found
>
> rails --version
>   Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use rvm http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ruby-on-rails/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion/

Comment: Try running `sudo rails --version`. I'm guessing it has something to do with folder permissions on the gems folder. I remember seeing this error when I installed rails on linux a while back before switching over to RVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem seems to have been that I already had an install of rails in /usr/bin which was in my PATH first.

This "install" was simply a shell script which gave the output above saying it's not installed.

I removed this by hand and reinstalled everything - after some messing around fixing random errors that it produced and a small edit to my PATH, it seems to be working now.